# gsutil api google storage nearline

Tags: python, encode, gsutil

I need to backup on the Google Storage, files having name with russian characters. Is there any solution? I get this kind of error:

**'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 203-213: ordinal not in range(128)**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're getting this error when trying to upload(copy) your files to the Google Cloud Storage using 'gsutil' tool.

In order to resolve the issue install UTF-8 version of your Russian font on your computer.

Comment: what OS are you running gsutil on? if it is CentOS try this command to see what is the value of LANG variable :   $ cat /etc/sysconfug/i18n